# Running multiple commands in one line in shell

Tags: bash, shell

Say I have a file `/templates/apple` and I want to

1. put it in two different places and then
2. remove the original.

So, `/templates/apple` will be copied to `/templates/used` AND `/templates/inuse`
and then after that I’d like to remove the original.

Is `cp` the best way to do this, followed by `rm`? Or is there a better way?

I want to do it all in one line so I’m thinking it would look something like:

```
cp /templates/apple /templates/used | cp /templates/apple /templates/inuse | rm /templates/apple
```

Is this the correct syntax?

Answer (score 1032, accepted):

You are using `|` (pipe) to direct the output of a command into another command. What you are looking for is `&&` operator to execute the next command only if the previous one succeeded:

```
cp /templates/apple /templates/used && cp /templates/apple /templates/inuse && rm /templates/apple
```

Or

```
cp /templates/apple /templates/used && mv /templates/apple /templates/inuse
```

---

To summarize (non-exhaustively) bash's command operators/separators:

- `|` pipes (pipelines) the standard output (`stdout`) of one command into the standard input of another one. Note that `stderr` still goes into its default destination, whatever that happen to be.
- `|&`pipes both `stdout` and `stderr` of one command into the standard input of another one. Very useful, available in bash version 4 and above.
- `&&` executes the right-hand command of `&&` only if the previous one succeeded.
- `||` executes the right-hand command of `||` only it the previous one failed.
- `;` executes the right-hand command of `;` always regardless whether the previous command succeeded or failed. Unless `set -e` was previously invoked, which causes `bash` to fail on an error.

Comment: Upvoted. Official documentation https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Lists

Answer (score 118):

Why not `cp` to location 1, then `mv` to location 2. This takes care of "removing" the original.

And no, it's not the correct syntax. `|` is used to "pipe" output from one program and turn it into input for the next program. What you want is `;`, which seperates multiple commands.

```
cp file1 file2 ; cp file1 file3 ; rm file1
```

If you require that the individual commands MUST succeed before the next can be started, then you'd use `&&` instead:

```
cp file1 file2 && cp file1 file3 && rm file1
```

That way, if either of the `cp` commands fails, the `rm` will not run.

Answer (score 12):

Note that `cp A B; rm A` is exactly `mv A B`. It'll be faster too, as you don't have to actually copy the bytes (assuming the destination is on the same filesystem), just rename the file. So you want `cp A B; mv A C`

Answer (score 10):

Another option is typing <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl+J</kbd> at the end of each command.

Example (replace `#` with <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl+J</kbd>):

```
$ echo 1#
echo 2#
echo 3
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
```

This will execute the commands regardless if previous ones failed.

Same as: `echo 1; echo 2; echo 3`

If you want to stop execution on failed commands, add `&&` at the end of each line except the last one.

Example (replace `#` with <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl+J</kbd>):

```
$ echo 1 &&#
failed-command &&#
echo 2
```

Output:

```
1
failed-command: command not found
```

---

In `zsh` you can also use <kbd>Alt+Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Esc+Enter</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl+J</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

Using pipes seems weird to me. Anyway you should use the logical `and` Bash operator:

```
$ cp /templates/apple /templates/used && cp /templates/apple /templates/inuse && rm /templates/apples
```

If the `cp` commands fail, the `rm` will not be executed.

Or, you can make a more elaborated command line using a `for` loop and `cmp`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this..

`cp /templates/apple /templates/used && cp /templates/apple /templates/inuse && rm /templates/apple`