# compile Qt project, get error QQmlEngine: No such file or directory compilation terminated

Tags: c++, qt

win10

QT5.7

I try to compile QT project through cmd

```
C:\Qt\Qt5.7.1\Examples\Qt-5.7\quick\demos\clocks>qmake -project

C:\Qt\Qt5.7.1\Examples\Qt-5.7\quick\demos\clocks>qmake

C:\Qt\Qt5.7.1\Examples\Qt-5.7\quick\demos\clocks>mingw32-make
```

output:

```
mingw32-make -f Makefile.Release
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Qt/Qt5.7.1/Examples/Qt-5.7/quick/demos/clocks'
g++ -c -pipe -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -O2 -std=gnu++11 -frtti -Wall -Wextra -fexceptions -mthreads -DUNICODE -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I. -I. -IC:\Qt\Qt5.7.1\5.7\mingw53_32\include -IC:\Qt\Qt5.7.1\5.7\mingw53_32\include\QtGui -IC:\Qt\Qt5.7.1\5.7\mingw53_32\include\QtANGLE -IC:\Qt\Qt5.7.1\5.7\mingw53_32\include\QtCore -Irelease -IC:\Qt\Qt5.7.1\5.7\mingw53_32\mkspecs\win32-g++  -o release\main.o main.cpp
In file included from main.cpp:40:0:
../../shared/shared.h:42:22: fatal error: QQmlEngine: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile.Release:198: recipe for target 'release/main.o' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [release/main.o] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Qt/Qt5.7.1/Examples/Qt-5.7/quick/demos/clocks'
Makefile:34: recipe for target 'release' failed
mingw32-make: *** [release] Error 2
```

this is the demo example of QT, and it works well at Qt creator. but report error at cmd. and no matter which demo I compile, they all report the same error which starts at `../../shared/shared.h:42:22: fatal error: QQmlEngine: No such file or directory`

P.S.:

actually, what I really want to do is to compile Qt project in sublime3, which failed and have no output. I began to use cmd to find the bug, and found out this error

my build system of sublime3 follows this post[Build system for Qt in Sublime Text 3 not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18934646/build-system-for-qt-in-sublime-text-3-not-working)

**add .pro file**

```
######################################################################
# Automatically generated by qmake (3.0) ?? 5? 29 09:05:15 2018
######################################################################

TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = clocks
INCLUDEPATH += .

# Input
HEADERS += ../../shared/shared.h
SOURCES += main.cpp
RESOURCES += clocks.qrc
```

this is what the qt demo writes

**update**
thanks to the comments, I add `QT += qml quick` in .pro file and solve the problem. although I don't know why the pro file generated by qmake -project commmand lack that statement

Comment: show your .pro .

Comment: have you checked if the file shared.h exists? How have you copied the example?

Comment: add `QT          += qml quick` to .pro, see http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-demos-clocks-example.html

Comment: That example already comes with a .pro so you should not use qmake -project.

Comment: @eyllanesc  yes, the file exists otherwise project will not work in Qt creator

Comment: So why did you delete the next line? `QT += qml quick` , http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-demos-clocks-clocks-pro.html

Comment: @ eyllanesc, I  didn't manually modfiy the .pro file. I think it may modify by qmake -project command.

Comment: Exactly, that command is used to create a .pro if it does not exist and could modify it, if that .pro exists then you just have to execute: qmake and mingw32-make

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the comments, I added `QT += qml quick` in .pro file and solved the problem.