# Docker Container Failing To Start On Boot

Tags: startup, docker

I am running an EC2 instance with a startup script that is called on reboot. This startup script checks that the docker daemon is running before then starting the container, but fails with the error: 
`Post http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.13/containers/create: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: no such file or directory`

**Startup Script**

```
# Make sure the docker daemon has started
sudo /usr/sbin/service docker start

# start the container
sudo /usr/bin/docker run -d 91b5261e2dc0
```

Please note that his is on an ec2 instance where "sudo" does not require password entry.

**Crontab entry:**

```
@reboot /bin/bash /home/ubuntu/start-container.sh 2> /home/ubuntu/cron_errors.log
```

**Errors:**

```
start: Job is already running: docker
2014/08/01 09:45:48 Post http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.13/containers/create: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: no such file or directory
```

Whenever I manually run the startup script, it works perfectly which makes it seem like an Environment variable/PATH issue to me. Googling around found information about not setting the DOCKER_HOST, but the startup script works fine even when DOCKER_HOST is still not set.

**What do I need to change or define to ensure the container starts correctly on startup?**

**Versioning Info**

OS: Ubuntu 14.04 Hardware Virtualized.

Docker version:

```
Client version: 1.1.2
Client API version: 1.13
Go version (client): go1.2.1
Git commit (client): d84a070
Server version: 1.1.2
Server API version: 1.13
Go version (server): go1.2.1
Git commit (server): d84a070
```

uname -a output

```
Linux ip-10-76-167-92 3.13.0-32-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 03:51:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Try adding a `wait` command (or a &&) after your first command in `start-container.sh`, failing that - are you sure your cron job is running as root? Try `@reboot root /bin/bash start-container.sh ...`

Comment: Adding a sleep 10 has "fixed" the issue temporarily, but I would rather not have to rely on a race condition. I am not running as root, but the default "ubuntu" user, hence the calls to sudo

Comment: That's fine, at least you know now that the docker daemon isn't starting in time for you to start your container. What about using `&&` at the end of the start command? You're effectively saying "When you're done starting the docker daemon, start the container". Basically the same as wait, though.

Comment: @Chris McKinnel are you saying that my call to `sudo /usr/sbin/service docker start` is non-blocking and it will immediately move onto the next line: `sudo /usr/bin/docker run -d 91b5261e2dc0` before the daemon has finished starting?

Comment: Yeah so if you take a look inside `/etc/init.d/docker`, you'll see that calling `start` uses the --background option to `start-stop-daemon` which means it's still doing stuff when it returns.

Comment: I'm afraid commands like `sudo /usr/sbin/service "docker" "start" &&  /usr/bin/docker run -d [IMAGE ID]` appear to never run the second half. I am guessing this is because && only works if the previous command succeeds and if the docker service is already running is not considered successful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "solution" ended up being to put in a sleep or a wait after the call to starting the docker daemon. E.g

```
# Make sure the docker daemon has started
sudo /usr/sbin/service docker start

# Wait for the docker daemon to finish starting
sleep 10

# start the container
sudo /usr/bin/docker run -d 91b5261e2dc0
```

This appears to be because as Chris McKinnel stated:

> ...if you take a look inside /etc/init.d/docker, you'll see that
>   calling start uses the --background option to start-stop-daemon which
>   means it's still doing stuff when it returns.

**Why not just use && ?**

I tried using `&&` to queue the starting of the container after the call to starting the docker daemon, but `&&` will only run the next command if the former was successful which isn't always the case (e.g. if the docker daemon is already running). [ [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130847/shell-multiple-commands-in-one-line) ]

Answer (score 3):

Another solution could be to run this container manually with --restart=always option:

```
docker run --restart=always -d 91b5261e2dc0
```

docker will run start all such containers after docker start and if container will stop without docker stop command.

Answer (score 1):

You can wait for the docker socket to become available before running your container:

```
# Start the docker daemon
sudo /usr/sbin/service docker start

# Wait for docker socket to become available
while [ ! -e /var/run/docker.sock ]; do sleep 1; done

# start the container
sudo /usr/bin/docker run -d 91b5261e2dc0
```