# Use Python in ubuntu to show contents of a directory

Tags: python, os.system

I have a .py file in the home directory which contains these three lines:

```
 import os

 os.system("cd Desktop/")
 os.system("ls")
```

and I want it to "ls" from the "Desktop" directory but it shows contents of the /home directory.
I looked at these pages:
[Calling an external command in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=729192
            but I could not understand what to do. Can anybody help me?

Comment: try os.system("ls Desktop/")

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use external processes, vs. `os.chdir` and `os.listdir`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shell - Multiple commands in one line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130847/shell-multiple-commands-in-one-line)

Comment: Also, side-note: If you _do_ need to run external processes, `os.system` is slower/less secure/less flexible than using the various `subprocess` functions. `os.system` launches all commands in a subshell (which introduces possible reliability and security issues with argument parsing, shell metacharacters, etc.), where something like `subprocess.check_call` with a `list` of the command and arguments is both faster and safer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I "cd" in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/431684/how-do-i-cd-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two calls are separate from each other. There is no context kept between successive invocations of `os.system` because a new shell is spawned for every call. First `os.system("cd Desktop/")` switches directories to `Desktop` and exits. Then a new shell executes `ls` in the original folder.

Try chaining your commands with `&&`:

```
import os

os.system("cd Desktop/ && ls")
```

This will show the contents of directory `Desktop`.

---

### Fabric

If your application is going to be heavy on `os` usage you might consider using [python-fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/). It allows you to use higher level language constructs like contextmanagers to make command line invocations easier:

```
from fabric.operations import local
from fabric.context_managers import lcd

with lcd("Desktop/"): # Prefixes all commands with `cd Desktop && `
    contents=local("ls", capture=True)
```

Comment: To be clear, the reason this happens when you use separate `os.system` invocations is that each `os.system` spawns a new shell to run the commands. So the new shell changes directories, then exits. Then a whole new shell is spawned (in the original directory, not the changed one) and runs.

Comment: "ls Desktop/"  would be shorter ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have to consider that `os.system` executes the commands in a sub-shell. Hence 1) python starts a sub-shell, 2) the directory is changed, 3) then the sub-shell is completed, 4) return to previous state.

To force the *current* directory change you should do:

```
os.chdir("Desktop")
```

*Always* try and do it by other means that through `os.system` (`os.listdir`), or also by doing other than `subprocess` (which is an excellent module for command control in the shell)