# Why doesn't the cd command work when trying to pipe it with another command

Tags: linux, bash, pipe, ls

I'm trying to use a pipeline with `cd` and `ls` like this:

```
ls -l | cd /home/user/someDir
```

but nothing happens.

And I tried:

```
cd /home/user/someDir | ls -l
```

It seems that the `cd` command does nothing while the `ls -l` will work on the current directory.

The directory that I'm trying to open is valid.

Why is that? Is it possible to pipe commands with `cd` / `ls`? 
Didn't have any problem with other commands while using pipe.

Comment: `cd` doesn't take input or generate output. Piping to/from it is meaningless.

Comment: Do you know what pipe does?

Comment: You don't mean just `ls /home/user/someDir -l` do you. If you mean the cd and then the ls, this is a possible duplicate of [Shell - Multiple commands in one line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130847/shell-multiple-commands-in-one-line)

Comment: See [Pipeline (Unix)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28Unix%29)

Comment: What result do you expect?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`cd` takes no input and produces no output; as such, it does not make sense to use it in pipes (which take output from the left command and pass it as input to the right command).

Are you looking for `ls -l ; cd /somewhere`?

Another option (if you need to list the target directory) is:

```
cd /somewhere && ls -l
```

The '&&' here will prevent executing the second command (ls -l) if the target directory does not exist.

Comment: not sure how being a shell builtin command prevents from using pipes, e.g. `echo | read`.  The key point here is no I/O for `cd`.

Comment: The other key point is that running `cd` in a pipe runs it in a subshell; it does not affect the shell in which `ls` runs.