# Combine two commands for the same line in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu-16.04

I need to execute two commands in the same line from the terminal. But it executed only the first command.

```
./build.py || cd /ns-3.20
```

That command only build was working and doesn't navigate to next directory.

Where am I get wrong?

Comment: use `;` to sequence commands

Comment: For sequential exectution use `./build.py; cd /ns-3.20`. the `|` is for chaining commands (unnamed pipe).

Comment: duplicate of [Running multiple commands in one line in shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130847/running-multiple-commands-in-one-line-in-shell). Please search, or even *re*search by reading the basic documentation of your terminal, before asking such questions.

Answer (score 1):

Change `|` to `;`:

```
./build.py; cd /ns-3.20
```

Comment: @M.David then you are "doesn't working" something wrong. What does that mean? Does not work is not a problem, unless we know what the does not work mean, errors? what happens?

Answer (score 1):

I would probably do:

`./build.py && cd /ns-3.20`

That way you only change directory if the build succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

you can use & :

```
 ./build.py & cd /ns-3.20
```

Comment: [root@f]# echo test
test
[root@f]# echo test & echo test2
[1] 14396
test2
test
[root@f]# echo test && echo test2
test
test2
[1]+  Fini                    echo test
[root@f]# true ; echo test
test
[root@f]# false ; echo test
test
[root@f]# false & echo test
[1] 14436
test
[root@f]# false && echo test
[1]+  Termine 1               false
[root@f]# true && echo test
test

Comment: This is same exemples

Answer (score 0):

With `./build.py || cd /ns-3.20` you only go to /ns-3.20 when the first command fails.
Is `/ns-3.20` a directory you can access and has some files you need for repairing the build?
When you want to go to that directory only after success, use `&&`. When you want there independant of the result, use `;`.

Comment: What is your error? Does `cd /ns-3.20` work, or should this be changed into `cd $HOME/ns-e.20` ?
Does `./build.py` execute ? 
Try `echo "Test"; pwd;cd /tmp'pwd; cd;pwd`

Answer (score 0):

Try the below command:

```
(./build.py &) ; cd /ns-3.20
```