# How to run 2 python files from command line, one after another?

Tags: python, bash

An example is:

```
python script1.py arg1 arg2

python script2.py arg1
```

where arg1 is from the first python call

Comment: You  can use `&&` to concatenate both commands https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130847/running-multiple-commands-in-one-line-in-shell

Comment: What do you mean by `where arg1 is from the first python call`, the input for second call is come from output of first call?

Answer (score 1):

How does script1 return its result? If it’s in stdout, try:

```
python script2.py $(python script1.py arg1 arg2)
```

`$(…)` runs the first script and takes the stdout output as the argument for the second script.

Comment: preferably: `python script2.py $(python script1.py arg1 arg2)`

Comment: Thanks for that. I found this that explains the difference: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082

Answer (score 0):

It is a matter of taste, to use either $(...) or backticks, I like backticks more:

```
python script2.py `python script1.py arg1 arg2`
```