# how do I call multiple commands in a single variable for bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, solaris

I have set of commands and I want all of them to be defined in a single variable. below are the commands I want display in output.

```
pwdx `ps -ef | grep java | cut -d' ' -f4` | cut -d/ -f7
```

I tried with

```
app=`pwdx `ps -ef | grep java | cut -d' ' -f4` | cut -d/ -f7` 
echo $app
```

but this gives empty output. Tried using for loop, that failed too.

Comment: can you try using () to those commands, Ex. $ (echo 111; echo 222; echo 333) which will give you an output 111 222 333.

Comment: Silly question, what do you see w/o the final cut?

Comment: @eight Stacker: If you had really written the command **exactly** as you posted it, your assignment to `app` should have brought several errors, for instance _bash: -ef: command not found_ and a syntax error for the `|` in front of the _cut_.

Comment: @eightStacker : Also, I don't understand your question. What is your goal? What does, for instance,  _I want display in output_ mean? I understand that you want to store into a variable a string which represents a series of commands. What do you want then to do with this string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `|&` operator to pipe the output (stdout and stderr) of the previous command into the standard input of another one:

```
pwdx `ps -ef |& grep java |& cut -d' ' -f4` |& cut -d/ -f7
```

See this write-up for more on executing several bash commands: [Running multiple commands in one line in shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130847/running-multiple-commands-in-one-line-in-shell)

Comment: Thanks for the reply mate, am trying to use a variable inside variable to execute it as a single command.. something like this... ``for i in `pwdx `ps -ef | grep java | cut -d' ' -f4` | cut -d/ -f7`; do echo $i ; done``