# Creating new line for output from commands

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, groovy

I'm using `sshpass` to get the output of different statistics of a machine.
 However the output is all bunched together:

```
sshpass -p *****_PASSWORD ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no mlinfra@$ADDRESS 'hostname; w; df -h; free'
```

Ideally I would like to have a new line in between the output of `hostname`, `w`, `df -h` and `free`

Answer (score 1):

It seems your question is just about formatting the output and independent from `sshpass` and `ssh`. So you could use just the `echo` command, i.e.:

```
ssh user@example.com 'hostname; echo; df -h; echo; free'
```

It will give you a new line in between the output of each command.

Thanks to

- [Which one is better using or to execute multiple commands in one line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/334994/)
- [Running multiple commands in one line in shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130847/)